# How can I define a command in the preamble with an optional argument for use in macros?

Tags: macros, titles

I'm trying to write tags to include document info which can be declared in the preamble then included in a title page using `\@institution` or `\@module`, similar to how LaTeX already includes `\title{}` to get `\@title`.

I need a command which has an optional "module number" and can be declared by `\module[PH588]{Mathematical Techniques}` in the preamble, to form tags like `\@mod@no` and `\@mod@title` (or similar) to be used in the title page as

```
{\Large \mod@no: \@mod@title \par}
```

and produce "PH588: Mathematical Techniques" in a large font.

I am new to this whole macro business and am only *fully* comfortable with basics like `\newcommand`. For other information I've used

```
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\renewcommand\@dept{#1}}
    \newcommand{\@dept}{}
```

to define each title element.

My attempts thus far (which have been fruitless) are along the lines of:

1)

```
\def\module[#1]#2{\gdef\@module[#1]{#2}}
    \def\@module{}
```

2)

```
\def\module{\@ifnextchar[{\@module@wno}{\@module@wono}}
    \newcommand{\@module}{}
        \def\@module[#1]#2{#1: #2}
        \def\@module#1{#1}
```

3)

```
\newcommand{\module}[2][no module number]{\@ifnextchar[{\renewcommand\@module@no[2]{#1}}{\renewcommand\@module}}
    \def\@module@no[#1]#2{#1}
    \def\@module#1{#1}
    \newcommand\@module@no[#1]#2{#1: #2}
    \newcommand\@module#1{#1}
```

These are all between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

As you can see I have very little idea what I'm doing, so if you could provide a simple explanation of how each part of your code does what it's doing and why that would really help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, the question is unclear to me. Why fruitless?

Comment: You are thinking too complicated, step back a little. Looking at package or kernel code isn't necessary a sign for good coding. Simply do as in your very first snippet and add `\renewcommand{\moduleno}{#1}`, which is the optional argument. The mandatory argument is now `#2`.

Comment: Most probably, the `\@module` stuff should be `'renewcommand`

Comment: If you think about adding a star feature somewhere, better familiarize yourself with package `xparse`, it will come in handy. And it might be handy here.

Comment: `\newcommand\a[2][x]{#1-#2}` will define `\a` so that `\a{b}` expands to `x-b` and `\a[y]{b}` to `y-b`.

Comment: @Johannes_B you are completely right, I think I just confused myself. All I needed was: `\newcommand{\module}[2][]{\renewcommand{\@mod@no}{#1}\renewcommand{\@mod@title}{#2}} \newcommand{\@mod@no}{} \newcommand{\@mod@title}{}`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something with the hard way using `\@ifnextchar` and the easy way with `xparse`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\providecommand{\@module@no}{}
\providecommand{\@module@title}{}


\newcommand{\module}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\module@@opt}{\module@@noopt}
}

\newcommand{\module@@opt}[2][no module number]{%
\renewcommand{\@module@no}{#1}%
\renewcommand{\@module@title}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\module@@noopt}[1]{%
  \module@@opt{#1}%
}


%\@onlypreamble{\module}


\NewDocumentCommand{\Module}{o+m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\@module@no}{#1}%
  }{%
    \renewcommand{\@module@no}{no module number}%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\@module@title}{#2}%
}


\newcommand{\printmoduleinfo}{%
{\large \textbf{\@module@no} \textsc{\@module@title}}%
}



\makeatother




\begin{document}

\module[The Fellowship of the Ring]{The Lord Of the Rings}


\printmoduleinfo

\module{The Lord Of the Rings}

\printmoduleinfo

\fbox{\textcolor{blue}{And now again with the xparse stuff}}

\Module[The two Towers]{The Lord Of the Rings}

\printmoduleinfo

\Module{The Lord Of the Rings}

\printmoduleinfo


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should group that `large`

Comment: @Johannes_B: Principally yes, but it's only a demo command, since there is nothing else known

Comment: Sure, still, should be grouped. The fiont will else be large, or fett or whatever for the rest of the doc. Though not really necessarry for the example, it's a bit of `best-practice`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: And I don't care :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you answered one of my questions the other day, too! I found the xparse part a little hard to follow but I'll look in to using that package for future endeavours. Thank you!

Comment: @HarrySmith: I've not answered a question of you till now ;-)

Comment: The test `\IfValueT{#1}` will always be true.

Comment: @egreg: Oh, yes, it's the rest of some code. I had `{om}` initially before I switched to `O{...}m`. I'll change

Comment: @egreg: Changed it, thanks for notifying me

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is

0)

```
\def\module[#1]#2{\gdef\mod@no{#1}\gdef\mod@title{#2}}
```

This defines `\module` macro for the usage `\module[num]{text}`. This macro defines `\mod@no` as `num` and `\mod@title` as text. It means that you can use later `\mod@no` which expands to `num` and `\mod@title` which expands to `text`. This is exactly, what you need.

Your bad attepts:

1)

```
\def\module[#1]#2{\gdef\@module[#1]{#2}}
\def\@module{}
```

After `\module[num]{text}` the macro `\@module` is defined with mandatory argument `[num]` (i.e. if you type something different from exactly `\@module[num]` then TeX will print an error). This very curious macro expands to the `text`. The setting `\@module` to empty macro via `\def` at line two is redundant.

2)

```
\def\module{\@ifnextchar[{\@module@wno}{\@module@wono}}
\newcommand{\@module}{}
\def\@module[#1]#2{#1: #2}
\def\@module#1{#1}
```

This is overcomplicated and bad. This defines `\module` as macro which looks to the next token. If it is `[` then `\@module@wno` is executed else `\@module@wono` is executed. But these macros are not defined.
Next, the `\@module` macro is defined as empty (the same as `\def\@module{}`). Next, this macro `\@module` is redefined as macro with one parameter in `[...]` and second in `{}`, The `\@module[num]{text}` expands to `num: text`. Finally, the `\@module` macro is redefined again, now with one parameter in `{}`, the `\@module{text}` expands to `text`. Why there are three definitions of the same macro? Only the last win. Why there are not defined the `\@module@wno`, `\@module@wono` macros?

3)

```
\newcommand{\module}[2][no module number]{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\renewcommand\@module@no[2]{#1}}{\renewcommand\@module}}
\def\@module@no[#1]#2{#1}
\def\@module#1{#1}
\newcommand\@module@no[#1]#2{#1: #2}
\newcommand\@module#1{#1}
```

This defines `\@module@no` and `@module` as an obscure macros via `\def`. Then the same macros are redefined via `\newcommand`, but `\newcommand` prints error because A) the macros are already defined and B) here is bad syntax for `\newcommand`. At the first line, the `\module` is defined via `\newcommand` as a macro with one optional parameter and one mandatory parameter, example of usage `\module[opt]{text}` or `\module{text}`. The second example behaves as `\module[no module number]{text}`. This macro looks to the next token and if it is `[` (i.e. the usage is `\module[opt]{text}[`) then it redefines `\@module@no` else it redefines `\@module` but does nothing more.

I tried to look at your code by TeX's eyes in order to show that all these codes are absurd. I recommend you to study how `\def` and macros in TeX behave. After such study, you will find out that the accepted solution is overcomplicated too.

Comment: Did you notice, that I used `\NewDocumentCommand` as well to shorten the syntax?

Comment: It seems that your thorough and useful explanations will be just as thorough and useful if you leave only the facts, and delete the editorial references to things being bad and absurd.  @HarrySmith clearly put genuine effort into the demonstrated solutions; what's the point of shaming him for mistakes?

Comment: @LSpice I don't shame him for mistakes because he know that there are mistakes (see the text: "As you can see I have very little idea what I'm doing, so if you could provide a simple explanation..."). I only provided the simple explanation as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy, with `xparse`, to define a command that *prints* what you want:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\module}{om}{%
  {\Large\IfValueT{#1}{#1: }#2\par}%
}
```

The `{#1: }` part is printed if you call `\module[PH588]{Mathematical Techniques}`, but not with the call `\module{Mathematical Techniques}`

If you need the optional module number and the module title in other places, then you can follow the same pattern:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@module@no}{} % initialize
\newcommand{\@module}{} % initialize

\NewDocumentCommand{\module}{om}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {% there is a module number
     \renewcommand{\@module@no}{#1}%
    }
    {% there is no module number
     \renewcommand{\@module@no}{}%
    }%
  \renewcommand{\@module}{#2}%
  % print the module title
  {\Large\IfValueT{#1}{#1: }#2\par}%
}
\makeatother
```

You'll be able to discriminate between the module number being currently available with an emptyness test such as

```
\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\@module@no}\relax
  <code for no module number>%
\else
  <code for available module number>%
\fi
```

Comment: I suppose, it should read `\IfValueTF` in your first code snippet?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, why? If no optional argument is given, `\IfValueT` returns false and does nothing.

Comment: Apparently I have missed that there is `\IfValueT` either